# Angular Directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

has anyone created any sample **Angular Directive** using `@Directive` *decorator*? I searched a lot on however all developers so far created component directives. Even  [Angular API Review](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive) doesn't speak more on this.

Comment: [Developer guides -> 12. Attribute directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html)...

Comment: Also, [Dev guide - 13. Structural Directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html), the _unless_ directive.

Comment: well explained answer here please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34616190/5043867

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Simple-Directive-Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/wlV8NgnqVnLezp3QkWEj?p=preview) . **This is a very simple example to start with angular2 directive**.

I have a component and directive.

I use directive to update component's view. Moreover **directive's changeColor function** is getting called with a **component's changeColor function**.

***Component***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  host: {'[style.backgroundColor]':'color',}
  template: `
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="color" (blur)="changeColor(color)" />
      <br>
      <span > (span) I'm {{color}} color <span>
      <div mySelectedColor [selectedColor]="color"> (div) I'm {{color}} color </div>
    `,
    directives: [selectedColorDirective]
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild(selectedColorDirective) myDirective: selectedColorDirective;
  color:string;
  constructor(el:ElementRef,renderer:Renderer) {
    this.color="Yellow";
    //renderer.setElementStyle(el, 'backgroundColor', this.color);
  }
  changeColor(color)
  {
    this.myDirective.changeColor(this.color);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() { }
 }
```

***Directive***

```
@Directive({

  selector:"[mySelectedColor]", 
    host: {
   // '(keyup)': 'changeColor()',
   // '[style.color]': 'selectedColor',
  }

  })

  export class selectedColorDirective { 

    @Input() selectedColor: string = ''; 

    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
      this.el=el;
        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'pink'; 
      // renderer.setElementStyle(el, 'backgroundColor', this.selectedColor);
    } 

    changeColor(clr)
    {
     console.log('changeColor called ' + clr);
     //console.log(this.el.nativeElement);
     this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = clr;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 10):

In Simple Terms
**Component Directive** will be your directives with template which we use a lot while building a app -> in your html -> `<custom-tag></custom-tag>`

```
@Component({
selector : 'custom-tag',
template : '<p> My Custom Tag</p>'
})
```

**Structural Directive** are the ones that modify the DOM, by removing adding elements. 
Example would be

```
<div *ngIf="showErrorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</div>
```

ngIf would add the div if true else remove if it changes to false.

Lastly are the **Attribute Directive**, the name says it all..its a 'attribute based directive'
Example would be :

```
<input type="text" pPassword />

@Directive({
    selector: '[pPassword]'
})
```

Answer (score 5):

There are three kinds of Angular directives:

```
Components
Attribute directives
Structural directives
```

Angular2 Guide Attribute Directives Code : https://github.com/guyoung/GyPractice-Angular2/tree/master/apps/attribute-directives

Angular2 Guide Structural Directives Code : https://github.com/guyoung/GyPractice-Angular2/tree/master/apps/structural-directives

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample directive. This add a event listener for click done outside a component.

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[clickedOutside]'
})
export class ClickedOutsideDirective {
  @Output()
  public clickedOutside = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private _elemRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event) {
    const targetElement = event.target;
    if (!targetElement) {
      return;
    }
    /**
     * In case the target element which was present inside the referred element
     * is removed from the DOM before this method is called, then clickedInside
     * will be false even if the clicked element was inside the ref Element. So
     * if you don't want this behaviour then use [hidden] instead of *ngIf
     */
    const clickedInside = this._elemRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if (!clickedInside && !this._elemRef.nativeElement.isSameNode(targetElement)) {
      return this.clickedOutside.emit(event);
    }
  }
}
```

This can be used as follows:

```
<app-comp (clickedOutside)='close()'></app-comp>
```

`close` will be triggered whenever someone clicks outside `app-comp`

Answer (score 0):

As per Angular2 docs, directives are used to change the behaviour of the DOM element.

Lets create one directive which would change the backgroundcolor of the div to red in case of mouseenter and yellow in case of mouseleave.

Step 1: Create Component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: '<div colorFlip>This is just a Demo!</div>'
})

export class MyComp {}
```

Step 2: Create Directive

```
import {Directive, HostListener, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[colorFlip]'
})

export class ColorFlip {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
  @HostListener('mouseenter') handleMouseEnter() {
    this.flipColor('red');
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') handleMouseEnter() {
    this.flipColor('yellow');
  } 

  flipColor(color:string) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
```

Step 3: Register Directive

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [MyComp , ColorFlip ]
})
```