# What are the examples of attribute directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, attributes, angular2-directives

I'm having difficulty in recognizing when should I

- create attribute directive,
- realize that I need to create attribute directive,
- use input and output properties

What is the need of attribute directive?

I tend to include all logic into one component, I know its definition but practically, I can't find examples.

What are the best practices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613065/what-is-the-difference-between-component-and-directive

Comment: Avoid putting the tags in the title unless it's a necessary part of the question. Best practices requests are off-topic on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

***Directives can be used to manipulate DOM element. It's so useful when you wanna make a custom (third party) directive that can be used by other programmers in your team or world.***

Basically there are three types of directives.

**1)** Structural Directive 
**2)** Attribute directives 
**3)** Component Directive(with template)

---

**1)** **Structural Directives** *usually manipulates structure of view/template. Eg. **`*ngFor`** will generate element according to your list count. **`*ngIf`** will display/hide view according to passed value*.

---

**2)** **Attribute directive** *allows you to add an attribute on DOM element and then you can do many things with that DOM element*.

eg.

```
<p myColor >Color me!</p>    //<<< this helps you to grab DOM element using ElementRef and then I'll color it as shown below.

import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[myColor]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';  
  }
}
```

here **`myColor`** is just an **`attribute directive`** as it is added to the DOM element as an **`attribute`** but this *attribute doesn't accept any value yet*.

Now let's add a value to **`myColor`** attribute,

```
<p [myColor]="color">Highlight me!</p>
```

---

**@Input** : Here we are passing **`color variable(Angular2 bindings)`** so in directive we must have a mechanism to receive it. So we should use **`@Input API`** as we are going to get value from parent component(you can consider directive as a child of parent)

---

**@Output** : If you want directive to emit some value that should be received by parent component then you should use **`@Output API`**

Comment: with attribute directive can we only change its styles and nothing?