# Micro syntax `as` not working with my own directive

Tags: angular, angular-structural-directive

I want to support the following micro syntax:

```
foo$ | async as xyz
```

Example:

```
<p *appVar="foo$ | async as xyz">
   Value is {{ xyz }}!
</p>
```

That stream is defined as

```
$foo = of('some value')
```

Here is my directive:

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[appVar]'
})
export class VarDirective<T> {
   @Input() appVar: T;

   constructor(
      private templateRef: TemplateRef<T>,
      private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
   ) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
   }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vqtgxk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fvar.directive.ts)

Now, whatever I do, that `xyz` variable is always undefined.

If I create a context (which is suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690622/custom-structural-directive-syntax-as-not-working) post)

```
 const context = { $implicit: this.appVar };
 this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, context);
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w8uvk7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fvar.directive.ts)

I get the same result. Any suggestions what I do wrong here?

Comment: try `(foo$ | async) as xyz`

Comment: Nope, same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression has to be available in the context under the same name as the directive itself, which is `appVar` in this case:

```
this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, {
  $implicit: this.appVar,
  appVar: this.appVar
});
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-du6tvm?file=src/app/var.directive.ts)

Compare it to the built-in [`ngIf`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e1f6d1538784eb87f7497bef27e3c313184c2d30/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L168) directive:

```
@Input()
set ngIf(condition: any) {
  this._context.$implicit = this._context.ngIf = condition;
  this._updateView();
}
```

and to the [`TuiLetContext`](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/taiga-ui/blob/a63b04d2d1c24065926f37a1b564ca4f50a8b9c6/projects/cdk/directives/let/let-context.ts):

```
get $implicit(): T {
  return this.internalDirectiveInstance.tuiLet;
}

get tuiLet(): T {
  return this.internalDirectiveInstance.tuiLet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is using "let" not "as". Some like

```
@Input() appVar

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef,
                {$implicit:this.appVar});
}
```

And use

```
<p *appVar="foo$ | async;let data">
  Value is {{ data}}!
</p>
```

But I feel that it's not what are you looking for :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be possible. For example TuiLet ([article](https://medium.com/its-tinkoff/how-taiga-ui-cdk-can-help-you-simplify-your-working-with-angular-our-5-best-practices-fd44809a8e2d)) does exactly the same thing. TuiLet [source code](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/taiga-ui/blob/main/projects/cdk/directives/let/let.directive.ts) file